# Return rows after a spatial join where the count is zero

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am trying to determine the number points in a table of polygons AND include a row of zero for those instances where a polygon has no points in it. This query works well except that no zero rows are outputted:

```
SELECT COUNT(h.points) AS "num_points", ws.polygons
                 FROM points_table as h
                 JOIN polygon_table as ws 
                 ON ST_Intersects(ws.geom, h.geometry)
                 GROUP BY ws.grouping_variable;
```

I tried using `COALESCE` like so:

```
SELECT COALESCE (COUNT(h.points), 0) AS "num_points", ws.polygons
                 FROM points_table as h
                 JOIN polygon_table as ws 
                 ON ST_Intersects(ws.geom, h.geometry)
                 GROUP BY ws.grouping_variable;
```

This successfully ran but didn't return any instances where the row equal zero. I think I am getting a little confused about the order of SQL. I am quite certain that one route is to take the "non-zero" output and LEFT JOIN it with the original `polygon_table` but I am not clear where that should actually happen.

In summary - how do I return rows after a spatial join where the count is zero as well as all the other counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the point count for each polygon, then use polygon for the first table, then a LEFT JOIN the points for zero or more matches. I've renamed a few things here:

```
SELECT poly.gid, COUNT(point.*) AS num_points
FROM polygon_table AS poly
LEFT JOIN points_table AS point ON ST_Intersects(poly.geom, point.geom)
GROUP BY poly.gid, poly.geom
ORDER BY poly.gid;
```

Comment: Did you mean to put a left join in there?

Comment: oh yeah, I did mean to do that!

Comment: ah well it happens!

Comment: That's it! Questions - 1) why did you rename things? 2) Any idea what type of resource demand `ORDER BY` has? I don't really need it and I am curious why you inserted it. 3) In `SELECT` how would I also return the geometry from poly?

Comment: Disregard #3 pls

Comment: 1) I renamed a few things because I could! Mostly to make the aliases 'point' and 'polygon' clear, and 'geom' consistent. Your unspecified table/columns names are possibly different. 2) minimal demand compared to the spatial operation, but you'll see the results in a consistent order. 3) poly.geom.